# How can i use chinese string in tsung

Tags: tsung

I'm china developer, i use `tsung` to test my application.

but now , i have problem,

this is my xml code.

```
<options>
   <option name="file_server" id="usernames" value="/usr/local/tsung/username.csv" />
  </options>

<sessions>
  <session name='rec20160406-1853' probability='100'  type='ts_http'>
    <setdynvars sourcetype="file" fileid="usernames" delimiter=";">
      <var name="user_name"/>
  </setdynvars>

  <request subst="true">
    <http url='http://10.2.0.96:3000/sessions?username=%%_user_name%%'>
    </http>
  </request>

</session>
</sessions>
```

username.csv

```
四方茉莉-Ra
宁靜致遠
阿莫西林
脸骑士
大嗨朵
右眼淤青
程子
这明显不科学
冰与火奏鸣曲
```

I want send `user_name` to my application, the `user_name` is read from `csv` file, the `csv` file is chinese content.
I start tsung, and watch the nginx access-log.
log:

```
192.168.60.61 - - [21/Apr/2016:17:17:29 +0800] "GET /sessions?username=\xE5\x86\xB0\xE4\xB8\x8E\xE7\x81\xAB\xE5\xA5\x8F\xE9\xB8\xA3\xE6\x9B\xB2 HTTP/1.1" 500 70 "-" "tsung"
```

the `user_name` encode to be `\xE5\x86\xB0\xE4\xB8\x8E\xE7\x81\xAB\xE5\xA5\x8F\xE9\xB8\xA3\xE6\x9B\xB2`, my application can not resolve this.

please help me , how can i to do.

Comment: link to github [issue](https://github.com/processone/tsung/issues/166)